# Javascript split and populate string

Tags: javascript

I had a string:

```
Pizza(food), Orange(fruit), Sandwich(food), lettuce(vegetable), Apple(fruit) 
,Burger(food)
```

And I want to populate the string as:

```
food: Pizza, Sandwich, Burger
fruit: Orange, Apple
Vegetable: lettuce
```

Comment: so, what are you waiting for? Auspicious time?

Answer (score 3):

Hardcore

```
var str = "Pizza(food), Orange(fruit), Sandwich(food), lettuce(vegetable), Apple(fruit) ,Burger(food)";
var obj = str.split(',').reduce(function(acc, token){
   token = token.trim().split(/\(|\)/).filter(Boolean);
   return (acc[token[1]]||(acc[token[1]] = [])).push(token[0]), acc;
}, {});

var newStr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
   return key + ': ' + obj[key].join(', ');
}).join('\n');
```

Comment: thanks for the quite solution yury! It works fine in the debug mode(f5). However, after i publish it on my local server. The function didnt work. Any ideal about it?

Comment: @0070 No idea. Have you wrapped this code with a function? What is used as an input? Can you recreate the issue here http://jsfiddle.net/ ? What browser are you using (this code uses some ES5 features as you can see)?

Answer (score 1):

More Hardcore:

```
var s = "Pizza(food), Orange(fruit), Sandwich(food), lettuce(vegetable), Apple(fruit) ,Burger(food)";

var result = s.split(",");

console.log(result);
var s1 = "food : ";
var s2 = "fruit : ";
var s3 = "vegetable : ";
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

    var item = result[i].replace(/\(/,"-").replace(/\)/,"").split("-");

    switch(item[1]){
        case "food":
            s1 += item[0] + " ";
            break;
        case "fruit":
             s2 += item[0] + " ";
            break;
        case "vegetable":
             s3 += item[0] + " ";
            break;

    }  
}

console.log(s1+"\n"+s2+"\n"+s3);
```